# Bottom Up Merge Sort Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I am trying implement a merge sort in Java. I know what I am trying to code but would appreciate a few pointer as I'm getting nowhere.

```
  int left=0;
    int right;
    int end;
    DataItem tempArray[] = new DataItem[data.length];
    String key;
    int t1;
    int t2;

    for (int j = 1; j <= data.length; j = 2 * j)//j = gtoup size
    {


        for (left =0; end<=data.length; left= left+ j)
        {
            t1=left;
            t2 = right;
                for (int i=left; i<end; i++)//for all elements across both sets
                {
                    key = data[t1].key;
                    if ((t1<right) && (t2>=end) || key.compareToIgnoreCase(data[t2].key) <0)
                {
                    tempArray[i] = data[t1++]; 
                }
                else
                {
                    tempArray[i] = data[t2++];
                }
            }
                for (int k = 0; k <= tempArray.length; k++)
                {
                    tempArray[k] = data[k];
                }
               right = left+j;
               end = right+j;

    }
  }
```

Here is the majority of my code.

What I'm trying to do is set right to be the current left + the group size. Then end becomes right +current group size. When the array has been fully traversed I am then wanting to double the group size and start again until groupsize is = end as this is when the sort has completed.

Any pointers of what area of the code I should be looking at greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards.

Comment: Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Try looking at [wiki merge sort article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) for the basic bottom up algorithm. It's not optimal, as it does a copy after each pass instead of swapping references (pointers).

Comment: Is this homework or self-study?